# Avaliando a resposta $http do factory para o controller no AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promises

Criei uma [Factory](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services) para realizar as operações [CRUD](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#M.C3.A9todos_de_solicita.C3.A7.C3.A3o) em uma [api REST](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/REST) usando o [$http service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) para fazer um controle de usuários.

**Factory**

```
//Listar..Recuperar ..Inserir ...Editar..{...}
usuarioService.Excluir = function (id) {
        var promise = $http({
            method: 'DELETE',
            url: API_URL.url + '/api/v1/usuario/' + id
        })
            .then(function (response) {
                return response.data;
            },
            function (response) {
                return alert(response.statusText + ' ' + response.data.errors + ' ' + response.data.message);
            });
        return promise;
    };
```

**Controller**

```
//Listar..Recuperar ..Inserir ...Editar..{...}
vm.Excluir = function Excluir() {
            usuarioService.Excluir(vm.id).then(function (result) {
                $location.path("/usuario");
            })
        };
```

Como posso capturar a resposta em casos de `erro` no meu `controller` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode passar diretamente a promessa e usar o `.catch` para tratar o erro.

Factory:

```
//Listar..Recuperar ..Inserir ...Editar..{...}
usuarioService.Excluir = function (id) {
  return $http({
      method: 'DELETE',
      url: API_URL.url + '/api/v1/usuario/' + id
  });
};
```

Controller

```
vm.Excluir = function Excluir() {
  usuarioService.Excluir(vm.id).then(function(result) {
    console.log(result.data);
    $location.path("/usuario");
  }).catch(function(response) {
    alert(response.statusText + ' ' + response.data.errors + ' ' + response.data.message);
  });
};
```

Comment: eu andei pesquisando existe ...um conceito chamado [Interceptors](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) vou ver se consigo implementar ele para fazer o tratamento de erros para os métodos de requisição HTTP... ainda estou estudando sobre isso por isso ainda não escolhi como resposta .... mas esse conceito e muito interessante acho que daria até para criar outra pergunta ...